# Better way to improve my helper with switch statement

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, switch-statement, helper

I have html helper, that get widget object from the List and then renders it into html code:

```
@helper RenderWidgetByType(Widget widget)
{

    @RenderWidgetHeader(widget.Header);
    switch (widget.Type)
    {
        case "Table": @RenderGrid((Grid)widget); break;

        case "Donut": @RenderDonut((Donut)widget);break;
    }

}
```

I have this classes:

```
public class Widget{}

public interface IWidget<T>{}

public class Grid : Widget{}

public class Grid<T> : Grid, IWidget<T>

public class Donut: Widget{}

public class Donut<T> : Donut, IWidget<T>
```

and all my widgets goes inside List Widgets, where after in foreach loop i work with each widget.

This code works fine. But I believe, there is a better way to do this. I don't see the solution at the moment, is there any way to improve my code somehow?

Comment: Take a look at a pattern matching switch statement: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching.  It will make your code slightly better - no more type strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the end of the day, I thought I'd flesh out my comment.  This is what I meant by a *"pattern matching switch statement"*:

```
 switch (widget)
 {
     case Donut donut: @RenderGrid(donut);
         break;
     case Grid grid: @RenderGrid(grid);
         break;
     //etc.
 }
```

It's ever so slightly cleaner - but it is easier to read.